# How can I get RealVNC to accept incoming connections in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-xp, vnc, realvnc

I have a system with XP, Vista, Windows 7 and now Windows 10. With RealVNC 4.1.3 installed on all machines I can remote in to every machine except for the Win 10. On the Win 10 machine I can connect to all other computers.

I found by accident that if I remove the two dll files from the execution directory and run winvnc4.exe the service starts and runs as long as the view window (which is hanging due to the missing dll's) stays open.

If the window closed or the server times out, the connections to the vnc on the Win 10 machine are gone and you get connection refused errors.

Anyone know what in Win 10 is killing the service when it is not being held in limbo? Or a registry hack to keep Win 10 from interfering with Real VNC?

Answer (score 1):

The installation of RealVNC should have installed a system service named "VNC Server".

Redo the installation if you cannot find this service in the Services applet.

If the service is already there, verify that its *Startup type* is "Automatic"
(set it if not already). Start it if not already started.

You probably have already signed-in using your RealVNC account credentials to
[license VNC Server](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/docs/licensing.html#licensing).